# Rails merge common attributes on a `has_many: through` model to show unique values based on another attribute of the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have the following models & relationships:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobs, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :job_technologies, through: :jobs
end

class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :job_technologies
  has_many :technologies, through: :job_technologies
  belongs_to :company
end

class JobTechnology < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :technology
end
```

Job technologies has this schema:

```
  create_table "job_technologies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "job_id"
    t.bigint "technology_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "title_matches"
    t.integer "description_matches"
    t.index ["job_id"], name: "index_job_technologies_on_job_id"
    t.index ["technology_id"], name: "index_job_technologies_on_technology_id"
  end
```

So when I create a `JobTechnology` I'm doing it like this:

```
JobTechnology.new(
        job: Job.new(title: 'some title'),
        technology: Technology.where(name: 'javascript').first,
        title_matches: 1,
        description_matches: 10
      )
```

This means if I want to see what technologies a job has I can do:

```
Job.first.job_technologies
=> [#<JobTechnology:0x00007ffc5b5957e0
  id: 647,
  job_id: 263,
  technology_id: 1,
  created_at: Mon, 31 May 2021 12:56:36 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Mon, 31 May 2021 12:56:36 UTC +00:00,
  title_matches: 0,
  description_matches: 2>,
 #<JobTechnology:0x00007ffc5b5953a8
  id: 648,
  job_id: 263,
  technology_id: 4,
  created_at: Mon, 31 May 2021 12:56:36 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Mon, 31 May 2021 12:56:36 UTC +00:00,
  title_matches: 1,
  description_matches: 2>,
 #<JobTechnology:0x00007ffc5b595100
```

This will always be a list of unique technologies because I'm only creating a `JobTechnology` for each unique technology (e.g. 'javascript', 'ruby', etc...) for each Job.

Now I want to see what technologies a company has. I can do:

```
Company.first.job_technologies
=> [#<JobTechnology:0x00007ffc56e3b9d0
  id: 647,
  job_id: 270,
  technology_id: 1,
  created_at: Mon, 31 May 2021 12:56:36 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Mon, 31 May 2021 12:56:36 UTC +00:00,
  title_matches: 0,
  description_matches: 2>,
 #<JobTechnology:0x00007ffc56e3b908
  id: 648,
  job_id: 271,
  technology_id: 1,
  created_at: Mon, 31 May 2021 12:56:36 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Mon, 31 May 2021 12:56:36 UTC +00:00,
  title_matches: 1,
  description_matches: 2>,
 #<JobTechnology:0x00007ffc56e3b818
  id: 649,
  job_id: 263,
  technology_id: 31,
  created_at: Mon, 31 May 2021 12:56:36 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Mon, 31 May 2021 12:56:36 UTC +00:00,
  title_matches: 0,
  description_matches: 1>,
 #<JobTechnology:0x00007ffc56e3b750
  id: 650,
  job_id: 263,
  technology_id: 32,
  created_at: Mon, 31 May 2021 12:56:36 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Mon, 31 May 2021 12:56:36 UTC +00:00,
  title_matches: 0,
  description_matches: 2>]
```

The problem is that `Company` can have `JobTechnologies` that are 'duplicate' technologies (imagine a `Company` has 5 `Job`s and they all have `JobTechnology` 'javascript'). You can see in above example we have

```
#<JobTechnology:0x00007ffc56e3b9d0
  id: 647,
  job_id: 270,
  technology_id: 1,
  created_at: Mon, 31 May 2021 12:56:36 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Mon, 31 May 2021 12:56:36 UTC +00:00,
  title_matches: 0,
  description_matches: 2>,
 #<JobTechnology:0x00007ffc56e3b908
  id: 648,
  job_id: 271,
  technology_id: 1,
  created_at: Mon, 31 May 2021 12:56:36 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Mon, 31 May 2021 12:56:36 UTC +00:00,
  title_matches: 1,
  description_matches: 2>,
```

I want to merge the `JobTechnology` so that we only have one `Technology` counted for each technology, but I want to aggregate the `title_matches` and `description_matches`. So the above example would become

```
#<JobTechnology:0x00007ffc56e3b9d0
  id: 647,
  job_id: 263,
  technology_id: 1,
  created_at: Mon, 31 May 2021 12:56:36 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Mon, 31 May 2021 12:56:36 UTC +00:00,
  title_matches: 1,
  description_matches: 4>
```

I could do this as a method on the `Company` that merges these manually, but I'd need to do this manually every time we search for this. I'm wondering if there's a less expensive way to achieve this.

I don't know much about caching but perhaps the best option is to do that - any links/thoughts/advice on this appreciated. I just have a feeling that there's a way to do this through an active record query without having to manually calculate it each time.

Another thought I have is whether I should create a `CompanyTechnology` model and perhaps that's where this logic should live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting `id`, `job_id`, `created_at` and `updated_at` as you outlined in your example doesn't make much sense. If the result is aggregated through 5 `JobTechnology`-s, which id should it be? I assume you don't care about it anyway. Lets focus on the items you clearly defined, `technology_id`, `title_matches` and `description_matches`.

What you're looking for is called `GROUP BY` in SQL. The equivalent in rails is `.group()`. We want to group the results by `technology_id` and for each `technology_id` aggregate (sum) the `title_matches` and `description_matches`.

```rb
Company.first.job_technologies.group(:technology_id).pluck(
  :technology_id, 'sum(title_matches)', 'sum(description_matches)'
)
```

This will return an array of arrays where every internal array has the 3 elements we're looking for.

To get rid of the sql literals we can use Arel for the same thing only safer.

```rb
Company.first.job_technologies.group(:technology_id).pluck(
  :technology_id,
  JobTechnology.arel_table[:title_matches].sum,
  JobTechnology.arel_table[:description_matches].sum
)
```

If you want to get an activerecord relation instead of an array of arrays, use `select` instead of `pluck`. However, be careful with it because since it doesn't have an id column, it might act a bit weird.